# Script Component transformation - unable to use variable with 'Row' to reference column values

Tags: c#, ssis-2012

I'm writing a code in the Script Component transformation task and have input metadata coming in from a previous task. I have field/column names stored in an array and want to be able to assign that using the variable in my code through by using 'Row'.

my input columns are
-SourceID
-SourceName
-SourceTrnDate

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
     string[] FieldNames = {"SourceId","SourceName","SourceTrnDate"};
     string[] FieldValue;
     string var;

     For(int i=0;i<3;i++)
     {    var = FieldNames[i];
          FieldValue[i] = Row.var; //Doesn't work 
     }
}
```

Comment: It is not that easy, The `Input0Buffer` class does not have a property named `var`, check this external link [sqlservercentral - Column property in Input0Buffer from script component?](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/column-property-in-input0buffer-from-script-component)

Comment: Thanks Cleptus it seems like that is what I need to do. Thank you.

Comment: Once you get it working, feel free to add an answer to your own question is not only allowed but encouraged